# position canvas on top of Scrollbar

Tags: javascript, css, html

I am simulation a projectile motion path. I've one div with css overflow property and a curve drawn using canvas. I want the motion path to appear at top of everything. But curve gets cut at the position where the scroll bar is. If i change the canvas z-index to maximum or something similar to make canvas to appear at top then the scrollbar doesnt work... here is a jsfiddle demo of my problem [JSFIDDLE Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/SURBC/)

Following is my javascript code:

```
  var canvas = document.getElementById('canvasTron');
  var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

  context.beginPath();
  context.moveTo(100, 150);
  context.lineTo(350, 50);
  context.stroke();
```

Is there any way to do that ???

Answer (score 0):

If you have no situation, but to go with what you have mentioned, here is the [solution](http://jsfiddle.net/SURBC/1/).

Addition in CSS:

```
#canvasTron{position:absolute; clip: rect(48px, 351px, 151px, 99px);}
```

With canvas, you cannot get the scroll to work effectively. As it will occupy the area of that div below it and will not make the scroll work.

The provided solution has to be purely applied in case of WORST CASE SCENARIO, where you are left with no option and have to do it under the existing circumstances. Otherwise, it is NOT POSSIBLE.

Comment: Scrollbar is not working in your solution. i want it to work as i mentioned in question

Comment: press on top and bottom arrows of the scrollbars to work. It wont work the way you want, as Canvas is a block of a square weather you draw a line or even a dot that extends width and height. CANVAS WILL NOT WORK ON A DIV BELOW IT TO SCROLL. - @Nitesh

Comment: hey why you unchecked the green tick :( - @Nitesh

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using canvas, You can do this :

```
<div id="canvasTron"></div>

canvasTron
{
     position:absolute;
     width:0px;
     height:200px;
     border:2px solid black;
     transform:rotate(50deg);
    -webkit-transform:rotate(50deg);
    -ms-transform:rotate(50deg);
    -o-transform:rotate(50deg);
    -moz-transform:rotate(50deg);
    left:180px;
}
```

Remains light weight and scrolling is also working fine.

Comment: I added that jsfiddle demo just to show my problem. I am simulating a projectile motion path. So i cant use transform properties.